# Do I need a different TOKEN to access customer-api for an XTRF server?

Tags: rest, xtrf

I am trying to access some data using "customer-api" for an XTRF server but I get below:

```
"status":401,"
errorMessage":"You are not authenticated or given credentials are incorrect, please re authenticate.",
"detailedMessage":null
```

I do have a token to access data through `home-api` for the same XTRF server. I access `customer-api` with the same token and got the error.

I used "curl" to access data as below:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-AUTH-ACCESS-TOKEN: MYTOKEN" "https://SERVER_ADDRESS/customer-api/quotes/5558"
```

I get the error message once I run the command above.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different token for Customer API as it is meant for different kind of user.

There are few ways to obtain token for Customer API:

- **Using login and password** 
  To get login and password go to Client profile in Home Portal, go to "Main data" and then "System Accounts". From here you can send welcome e-mail then set-up the account for it. (You can also choose "Sign in as this Partner" and by using developer console in your browser extract JSESSIONID - that's the token).

Once you have an account, you can do the following request to obtain token:

```
POST /system/login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "username": "my login",
 "password": "my password"
}
```

- **Using token from Home Portal**
  On Home Portal API you can use `POST /customers/persons/accessToken` with the following body:

```
{
  "loginOrEmail": "personLogin"
}
```

to obtain pre-auth token for customer contact person. Then by doing

```
POST /system/loginWithToken HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "accessToken": "qwertyuiop"
}
```

on the Customer API you can obtain actual JSESSIONID that you can use as a token for Customer API requests.